# Use jq to transform a date value then filter by it

Tags: jq

I have some data which takes the following format:

```
[
  {
    "level": "error",
    "ts": "2021-09-08T17:34:39.163Z",
    "caller": "controller/events.go:39",
    "msg": "Metric query failed for p50 Latency: request failed: Get \"https://blah\": context deadline exceeded",
    "canary": "blah",
    "stacktrace": "github.com/fluxcd/flagger/pkg/controller.(*Controller).recordEventErrorf\n\t/workspace/pkg/controller/events.go:39\ngithub.com/fluxcd/flagger/pkg/controller.(*Controller).runMetricChecks\n\t/workspace/pkg/controller/scheduler_metrics.go:280\ngithub.com/fluxcd/flagger/pkg/controller.(*Controller).runAnalysis\n\t/workspace/pkg/controller/scheduler.go:682\ngithub.com/fluxcd/flagger/pkg/controller.(*Controller).advanceCanary\n\t/workspace/pkg/controller/scheduler.go:380\ngithub.com/fluxcd/flagger/pkg/controller.CanaryJob.Start.func1\n\t/workspace/pkg/controller/job.go:39"
  },
  {
    "level": "error",
    "ts": "2021-09-09T11:22:33.162Z",
    "caller": "controller/events.go:39",
    "msg": "Metric query failed for p50 Latency: request failed: Get \"https://blah\": context deadline exceeded",
    "canary": "blah",
    "stacktrace": "github.com/fluxcd/flagger/pkg/controller.(*Controller).recordEventErrorf\n\t/workspace/pkg/controller/events.go:39\ngithub.com/fluxcd/flagger/pkg/controller.(*Controller).runMetricChecks\n\t/workspace/pkg/controller/scheduler_metrics.go:280\ngithub.com/fluxcd/flagger/pkg/controller.(*Controller).runAnalysis\n\t/workspace/pkg/controller/scheduler.go:682\ngithub.com/fluxcd/flagger/pkg/controller.(*Controller).advanceCanary\n\t/workspace/pkg/controller/scheduler.go:380\ngithub.com/fluxcd/flagger/pkg/controller.CanaryJob.Start.func1\n\t/workspace/pkg/controller/job.go:39"
  }
]
```

I am trying to filter this data by date, e.g. I want to find all of these events after a certain date. The timestamp `1631122500` should filter out the top entry here (with `ts` == `2021-09-08T17:34:39.163Z`).

If I apply the command `| jq -s '.[] | select(.ts | fromdateiso8601 > 1475625600)'`, it returns the error `jq: error (at <stdin>:8): date "2021-08-30T21:52:34.039Z" does not match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`.

I have managed to amend the `ts` field by applying the following modifications: `jq -s '.[].ts | split(".")[0] | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") | mktime | strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")'`. This returns values like `"2021-09-08T18:34:39Z"` which is the format specified in the aforementioned error.

What I can't get my head around is how I can transform each of these `ts` values to the correct format, then use `select` to filter by dates since a specified time. I tried piping `jq <modify>` to `| jq <select>` but this gave me an error about jq being unable to iterate over strings.

Comment: Are your timestamps in the same timezone?

Comment: Yeah @0stone0. The difference between the format JQ requires and the data I've got is that mine has nanoseconds, I think.

Comment: Yea, I'd recommend removing those, then JQ will parse the date just fine.

Comment: I can't alter the actual data, which is why I'm trying to apply a transformation then select by it. I can transform the date to the correct value required by JQ, but I don't then know how to use this transformed date in a `select` filter.

Comment: `1631122500` should exclude the `2021-09-08T17:34:39.163Z` timestamp

Comment: Mmm, sure al those `0` are ment to be there? Using `1631122500` only shows the `2021-09-09T11:22:33.162Z` object with the command shown below.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I edited... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69116628/use-jq-to-transform-a-date-value-then-filter-by-it#comment122156960_69116628):

> which is why I'm trying to apply a transformation then select by it. I can transform the date to the correct value required by JQ

---

Right after calling `select`, we can pipe the `.ts` value to remove the nanoseconds which JQ can't parse like so:

```
jq 'map(select(.ts | (split(".")[0] + "Z") | fromdateiso8601 > 1631184310))'
```

The above timestamp (`1631184310`) will just select the second object as you can [try online here](https://jqplay.org/s/gWVcZQMjgY)

Comment: Much neater! Thanks very much.